# get value from piped and inner observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have the following code where I want to get an item from the store, apply a function to that value, and return both the value of the store and the modified one

```
this.store$.pipe(select(carPositions), take(1)).pipe(
   mergeMap(positions => modify(positions))))
).subscribe((original, modified) => {
    //do some stuff
})
```

the problem is, the above code return only the modified, but not the original.

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) to delegate `positions`, from their docs:

> When any observable emits a value, emit the last emitted value from each.

Your should be:

```js
this.store$
  .pipe(
    select(carPositions),
    take(1),
    mergeMap(positions => {
      return combineLatest(of(positions), modify(positions));
    })
  )
  .subscribe(([original, modified]) => {
    //do some stuff
  });
```

Comment: I think that the parameter passed as input in the subscribe function is a tuple like `[original, modified]`

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `modify(positions)` returns an Observable, otherwise `mergeMap` would not work.

If this is the case, than you can try something like this (read the inline comments for some details)

```
this.store$.pipe(
  select(carPositions), 
  take(1),
  mergeMap(positions => modify(positions).pipe(
       // map the notification of modify so that it returns also the positions in a tuple
       map(modified => {
          return [positions, modified]
       })
    )
  )
)
// the value emitted is the tuple generated above
.subscribe(([positions, modified]) => {
    //do some stuff
})
```

You basically enrich the result emitted by `modify(positions)` with the parameter `positions` using the `map` operator to return a tuple with both values. This is a typical patern when using rxjs.